# Alternative to Hystrix for Request Collapsing

Tags: cloud, microservices, hystrix, resiliency, resilience4j

as Netflix put Hystrix officially into maintenance mode (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix#hystrix-status), I started to look for alternatives. There are nice libraries like resilience4j when it comes to patterns like Circuit Breakers, Bulkheads, Retries and these things, but I cannot find an alternative for the request collapsing, that Hystrix can do.

Is anyone aware of a library, that can provide such functionality?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Varnish Cache can be used for request coalescing or request collapsing.

> [...] What happens is that as a request is sent to the backend, a “busy
>   object” is created. If another client comes along and requests the
>   same page Varnish will see the busy object and put the request on a
>   waiting list for a corresponding response. When the response returns
>   Varnish will distribute the response to all the clients on the waiting
>   list. [...]

(see this [blog](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/hit-for-pass-varnish-cache) for more information)